# I got this while updating - "W: Failed to fetch ..... 404 Not Found"

Tags: updates

I am new to this system and getting

```
W: Failed to fetch http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-security/multiverse/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found
```

these kind of errors and warnings while updating.
I have tried lot of things but nothing worked.
Current situation of my terminal is:

I have run:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-cache policy
inxi -r
cd /etc/apt/sources.list.d
ls -la
```

What should I do? 
Help me to get out of this problem as I won't be able to get things without this problem is being solved.

Comment: That repository doesn't exist.

Comment: Why is that on `old-releases.ubuntu.com`? 14.04 isn't an old release. You should edit it so it doesn't include the `old-`.

Answer (score 0):

That is a non-existant repository at the moment for 14.04 is not an old End-Of-Life release which has had its repositories archived. To solve the problem edit the file `/etc/apt/sources.list` and any files in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d` which have the `old-` in them (did you edit the files to contain this because this shouldn't be and isn't default?) and edit it out.